# pop until in flutter auto route package does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-routes

I am using the AutoRoute package for Flutter.

I have the following two screens generated using the auto route package,

```
HomeRoute()
ProductsRoute()
```

Then from `HomeRoute`I do the following,

```
context.router.push(const ProductsRoute());
```

Then inside the `ProductRoute` I call an API in the `initState` and if I an error occurs, I show a pop up that says `Something went wrong!`. Here,

**I want to pop the alert, then pop the `ProductsRoute()` so that the user navigates back to the `HomeRoute()`.**

So using the `AutoRoute` I did the following,

```
context.router.popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == 'HomeRoute')
```

This did not work. It leads me to a white screen.

However it does work if I do `context.route.pop()` twice.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I navigate back to the `HomeRoute()` using the Auto Route package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem,

With `popUntil`, if I want to go to the `HomeRoute`, I should not mention the `HomeRoute`. Instead I should mention the route on the stack that is after the `HomeRoute`. Then it started to work,

For example suppose I have the following stack,

ScreenA -> ScreenB -> ScreenC -> ScreenD

Now if I want the user to show `screen A` by popping all the screens from `screen D`,

I should do,

```
context.router.popUntilRouteWithName(ScreenBRoute.name);   // <---- Should do
```

**NOT**

```
context.router.popUntilRouteWithName(ScreenARoute.name);   // <---- Should not do
```

Answer (score 0):

```
context.router.popUntil((route) => route.name == 'HomeRoute')
```

or

```
context.router.popUntilRouteWithName('HomeRoute')
```

Comment: "The getter 'name' is not defined for the type 'Route<dynamic>'"

Comment: @genericUser Use route.settings.name